# Deform/Displace a mesh but keep perimeter

Tags: modeling, modifiers, displacement

I am currently working on a device called APOBS and a key part of the model is a rope which contains explosive devices shaped like grenades.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Bar4UOK.jpg]

After I worked on the mesh of the roping inside the container I now have to deform parts of the mesh to look like its made of fabric.(The model obviously needs more polishing)

[image]

Thats where I have been struggling. My approach has been using the deform modifier in combination with a cloud texture. However by doing so the mesh is being deformed and the proportions of the mesh change. Meaning that the diameter of the roping also changes. Obviously the roping is supposed to have the same proportions and I only want to achieve the displacement to make it look more realistic.

[image]

So to conclude the approach I have been using does not lead to a statisfying result and my question is "Is there maybe a different way that actually achieves the fabric displacement I am striving for?"

Edit1:
After asking someone who has mainly experience with 3DSMax he was able to come up with something that is approximately what I need.

[image]

Edit2: edited title

Comment: Have you tried to shrinkwrap a fabric cylinder?

Comment: I dont understand how that would lead to the result I desire. Would you mind elaborating?